# Monotouch how to know if its the first time I run the app (new version)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have my IOS Application that has a local resource `SeedData.mxl` (build action -> content) that the first time the app is installed, the `XML` file is loaded into a `SQLite`.

This works perfect but know I have the need to modify this SeedData.mxl for a new version of the app that I will publish.

> The problem is that users that are using the last version of the app have a SeedData.xml with a different structure of the new one. Because for them this is not a new installation, its just an update of version, the SeeData.xml will not loaded into `SQLite` **unless I can detect in my app that it's the first time the user runs an updated version of the app.**

Is there a way to do this? Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a check on your SQLite database to see if it has the correct table structure on app startup. If not, you know you need to update it before you add your new data.

Comment: You just give me a better idea :), I will add in the XML SeedData a version. Then I will just validate this :). I think might work I will try